# How to create a TensorFlow 2 SavedModel with more than 1 signatures?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I used `tf.saved_model.save` and `tf.saved_model.load` to save and load TF2 SavedModel. According to [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/save#used-in-the-notebooks), I created a signature and this signature is `serving_default`. Then I try to add a new function with signature decorator in class `Adder`. But after I loaded the model according to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load), I find that the signatures disappear in the model, i.e., `print(adder1.signatures)` prints no signature names. I don't find any information about how to use multiple signatures while saving models. So can anyone provide me with some information? Thank you very much.

Tensorflow `2.1.0`, on Google Colab. The code looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd

class Adder(tf.Module):

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.float32), tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.float32)])# 
  def add(self, x, y):
    return x + y ** 2 + 1

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.float32)])
  def square(self, x):
    return x ** 2

to_export = Adder()
tf.saved_model.save(
    to_export, 
    '/tmp/adder'            
)

adder1 = tf.saved_model.load("/tmp/adder")
print(adder1.signatures)
adder1_sig = adder1.signatures["serving_default"]
adder1_sig(x = tf.constant(1.), y = tf.constant(2.))
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?